# Как инвертировать только определённые биты в числе

Tags: c++, битовые-операции

Мне нужно инвертировать все биты в числе, допустим, `2` (`10` в двоичной системе) после инвертирования будет равно `01`. Но столкнулся с проблемой, что операция побитового отрицания инвертирует также и знаковый бит и вообще все биты, которыми число представлено в памяти. И получается, что:

```
int a = ~2; // -3
```

Как мне всё-таки получить `1`, а не `-3`?

Comment: как же так, 2 - это ...00010 после инвертирования будет...11101. Поставьте явную задачу

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вообще-то битовые операции не стоит применять к знаковым целым числам, поэтому я пишу сразу для `unsigned`.

Увы, из вашего задания мало что понятно. Вы хотите, похоже, инвертировать только биты, начиная со старшего единичного бита?

```
000010000101 -> 000001111010
000011111111 -> 000000000000
```

Так?

```
unsigned int inv(unsigned int x)
{
    unsigned int mask = 0;
    for(unsigned int y = x;y;y>>=1)
        (mask <<= 1) |= 1;
    return (x == 0) ? 1 : (x^mask);
}
```

Здесь для 0 все же инвертируем его в 1.

Но вот не уверен, что вы хотите для 7 или там 3 инвертирование в 0 - все их единички.

А вообще - нужно очень точное ТЗ, иначе результатом будет ХЗ...

С тем же успехом, для @avp:

```
    mov eax, d
    bsr ecx, eax
    inc ecx
    mov ebx, 1
    shl ebx, cl
    dec ebx
    dec ebx
    or  ebx, 1
    xor d, ebx
```

Comment: [__builtin_clz(x)](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html) -- обычно эту функцию используют вместо цикла для конструирования подобных масок

Comment: @avp Ну, если идти по пути расширений... см. добавку в ответе :)

Comment: @Harry, я поэффективнее придумал :)

Comment: @Qwertiy 5 баллов!

Answer (score 3):

По сути, вам надо инвертировать то количество бит, которым представляется число в двоичной системе. (7 dex - 111 bin, тут 3 цифры. 8 dex - 1000 bin, тут четыре цифры)

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>

unsigned int invert(unsigned int a) {
    // количество цифр числа a в системе счисления 2 
    unsigned int shift = (unsigned int)std::log2(a) + 1u;
    return (shift == 32) ? ~a : (~a & ((1u << shift) - 1u));
}

int main() {
    std::cout << invert(2) << '\n'; // 1
    std::cout << invert(8) << '\n'; // 7
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Тоже неплохой вариант, ограничение разрядной сетки and-ом. А цикл заменили двоичным логарифмом - который показывает степень (т.е. разрядность числа). Я бы упростил до такого `~a&((1<< shift)-1)` или что-то такое.

Comment: Ещё чем нравится этот вариант - в декомпрессорах часто похожая конструкция используется (только вместо логарифма таблица).

Answer (score 2):

Для uint32 вот так:

```
unsigned inv(unsigned x)
{
  unsigned y = x;

  y |= y >> 1;
  y |= y >> 2;
  y |= y >> 4;
  y |= y >> 8;
  y |= y >> 16;

  return x ^ y;
}
```

Для других размеров надо поменять количество сдвигов.

Код полностью: https://ideone.com/02KvkC; результат инвертирования:

```
0 0
1 0
2 1
3 0
4 3
5 2
6 1
7 0
255 0
256 255
317 194
402 109
7200 991
86123456 48094271
1000000000 73741823
1234567897 912915750
```

Comment: Здорово! Вам прямо [сюда](https://www.hackersdelight.org/)

Answer (score -1):

Хотите работать с битовым представлением в C++ - для этого есть специальный класс [`std::bitset`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset). Вот небольшой [пример использования](https://wandbox.org/permlink/WiBJN2mjYMy4LYKp) для вашего случая:

```
#include <bitset>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::bitset<2> b(2);
    std::cout << b << ' ' << b.to_ulong() << '\n';
    b.flip();
    std::cout << b << ' ' << b.to_ulong() << '\n';
}
```

Функция [`flip`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/flip) позволяют как инвертировать все биты, так и конкретные.

Comment: Проблема bitset'а в том, что он требует размер времени компиляции. С рантайм числом так легко уже не получится. Не понимаю, почему его не сделали динамическим

Comment: @DrawnRaccoon Для ускорения, на template будет сгенерирована конкретная ф-ция константами заточеная на двойку, и не будет кучи вычислений масок.

Comment: @DrawnRaccoon хотите динамический размер - используйте `std::vector<bool>`.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ я бы использовал, будь у него такой же интерфейс как у bitset'а

Answer (score -1):

Еще вариант

```
int a;
cin >> a;
std::bitset<32> b = a;
cout << b << endl;
if (b.none()) b = 1;
else {
    int i = b.size() - 1;
    while (!b.test(i)) --i;
    for (int j = 0; j <= i; ++j)
        b.flip(j);
}
 cout << b;
```

Comment: Громоздко довольно.

Comment: @nick_n_a, это не означает, что неправильно(к вашему сведению), а это означает, что есть много вариантов

Comment: Хорошо. Вариант рабочий